# when is webrick different from development.log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webrick

Running with a default configuration, I have yet to see an instance where messages appeared in the webrick window but not in development.log or vice versa.  Does anyone know of specific messages which I should expect to appear in only one of the two locations?  Is there good doc describing how Rails' processing directs output to the two locations (webrick and log file)?

Answer (score 0):

Server output for WEBrick is logged in both stdout and to `log/development.log` in when Rails is in development. The log level for Rails in development is set to `:debug` by default, so you can expect to see `:debug`, `:info`, `:warn`, `:error`, and `:fatal` log messages in both places.